# Angular 4 and Jhipster i18n translateValue using string with character ':' inside

Tags: angular, internationalization, jhipster

I'm new using internationalization; I'm working with **angular 4** and **jhipster** *version 4.6.0*.

I have in the folder i18n/en a file called actionProcess.json, inside of this file this properties:

```
{
    "actionProcess": {
        "title": "{{ action }} {{ name }}",
        "action": {
            "run": "Are you sure to do {{ action }} over {{name}}"                
        }
    }
}
```

and inside of a popup in the html

```
<p jhiTranslate="actionProcess.action.run" translateValues="{action: '{{getAction()}}', name: '{{name}}'}">Are you sure you want to delete?</p>
```

I spec for *name*: 'test' and *action*: 'run': 
**Are you sure to do *run* over *test***

It's work for me but for some reason i need to pass a name with this example patter [a-z]+:[a-z]+, but in this case for *name*: 'testString:aa' (containing **:**) and *action*: 'start', this happen

```
Expected a valid Object, received: {action: 'start', name: 'testString:aa'}
```

How resolve that...

Comment: Also trying to find a solution to this issue. Issue also happens with Angular 5. Problem also occurs if a property (like here - name) contains \, ', ", * in the value.

Comment: Same problem here !